# Insert new row before each duplicated ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames SF and OF.

SF:

```
ParentPartNumber   Webname       Brand 
     2                Sidi         Si
     2                Sidi         Si
     2                Sidi         Si
     3                Shoei        Sho
     3                Shoei        Sho
```

OF:

```
SKU      Published         Name
 2          1              Sidi
 4          1              Bec
 8          1              Lin
```

What I want to do is to add an extra row before each duplicated row present in SF and append it to the OF data frame. For example, if there are duplicates in a parent like 2,2,3,3 the first row of 2 and the second row of 2 needs to be copied, and in addition to all rows, there have to be an extra one added before them with info as in the description. So the end result should look like

Result (SF rows appended in OF):

```
SKU      Published         Name
 2          1              Sidi
 4          1              Bec
 8          1              Lin
 2 (extra)  1              Sidi
 2          0              Sidi
 2          0              Sidi
 2          0              Sidi
 3 (extra)  1              Sho
 3          0              Sho
 3          0              Sho
```

What I have done so far is taken the unique values and stored them in an array, then I have used a loop to create a row and append the needed information, my code looks like this

```
duplicate = SFs['ParentPartNumber'].unique()


for i in duplicate:
    OF = OF.append(pd.DataFrame({'SKU': SFs[SFs['ParentPartNumber']==i]['ParentPartNumber'].values, 'Published' : '1', 'Name': SFs[SFs['ParentPartNumber']==i]['WebName']}), sort=False, ignore_index=True)
```

However, I am getting a result like

```
SKU      Published         Name
 2          1              Sidi
 4          1              Bec
 8          1              Lin
 2          1              Sidi
 2          1              Sidi
 3          1              Sho
```

I know what is wrong just have no idea how to fix it? How can I get the results mentioned above. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key of the solution is using `DataFrame.duplicated` to find all the duplicated rows and `DataFrame.drop_duplicates` to keep the first row of each duplicated rows.

As SF has an index order, so finally you can use `DataFrame.sort_index` to keep the orgin row order.

```py
# create a DataFrame keep SF all duplicated rows
cond = SF.duplicated(keep=False)
df = SF.loc[cond, ['ParentPartNumber', 'Webname']].copy()
df['Published'] = 0

# rename columns, and sorted columns
df.columns = ['SKU', 'Name', 'Published']
df = df[OF.columns].copy()

# drop duplicates(keep the first duplicate row), and assign 1 to Published column
dfn = df.drop_duplicates(keep='first').copy()
dfn['Published'] = 1

# append first duplicate row to df, and sort index to keep row order
dfn = dfn.append(df).sort_index()

# append the duplicates rows to OF
print(OF.append(dfn))
```

```
  SKU  Published   Name
0    2          1   Sidi
1    4          1    Bec
2    8          1    Lin
0    2          1   Sidi
0    2          0   Sidi
1    2          0   Sidi
2    2          0   Sidi
3    3          1  Shoei
3    3          0  Shoei
4    3          0  Shoei
```

Comment: Thanks , but what if I only want to find duplicated parentnumber? Not the complete row, the rest is the same

Comment: Hi, there is some issues with the indexing. It is not giving the exact match

Comment: Maybe you can add more information about the desired output you wanted. like generating more demo data.